# Compiling Python 3.4 is not copying pip

Tags: python, compilation, pip, python-3.4

I have compiled Python 3.4 from the sources on Linux Mint, but for some reason it is not copying `pip` to its final compiled folder (after the `make install`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just sorted it out. Here it is how to compile python from the sources.

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/home/user/sources/compiled/python3.4_dev --with-ensurepip=install
$ make
$ make install
```

If you get "Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 1.5.4 requires SSL/TLS" error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev openssl 
$ ls
2to3              idle3    pip3.5    python3           python3.5m         pyvenv
2to3-3.5          idle3.5  pydoc3    python3.5         python3.5m-config  pyvenv-3.5
easy_install-3.5  pip3     pydoc3.5  python3.5-config  python3-config
```

As you can see pip is copied into target folder, the `--with-ensurepip=install` is important.

Comment: I'd bet it was the missing openssl requirement that blocked ensurepip from running (as pip requires ssl connections by default).

Comment: libssl-dev is openssl-devel with centos

Answer (score 4):

If you are in Redhat linux (centos, fedora) install following package.

```
yum install openssl-devel -y
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [PEP 453 -- Explicit bootstraping of pip in Python installation](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0453/#installing-from-source):

> ### Installing from source
>
> Just as the prebuilt binary installers will be updated to run python
>   -m ensurepip by default, **a similar change will be made to the make install and make altinstall commands of the source distribution**. The
>   directory settings in the sysconfig module should ensure the pip
>   components are automatically installed to the expected locations.

After installing from source code, I found that `pip3.4` is put in the destination. (No `pip` nor `pip3`)